# how to show a loading div for 5 second when button click then redirect to next page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a quiz project. after giving answer when a user clicked the button I want to add a loading div for 5 second then redirect to win or lost page.Also let me know the css to cover whole screen.

below my code but this not working for 5 seconds...

```
<div id="spinner" style="display:none">
  <img src="/sites/all/modules/custom/admin_job/assets/images/spinning-loading.gif">
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
  $('#edit-submit').click(function(){
    $("#spinner").show();
  setTimeout(function() { $("#spinner") }, 5000);
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: What should `$("#spinner")` do in your timeout function?

Comment: I think you forgot `$("#spinner").hide()` in the timeout function

Comment: the div will show for 5 seconds.

Comment: `$("#spinner")` itself will do nothing

Comment: what should I put in timeout function then?

Answer (score 1):

As I said in my comment you miss a `.hide()` in you timeout function

```js
$(() => {
  $('#button').on('click', () => {
    $('#spinner').show()
    setTimeout(() => {
      $('#spinner').hide();
    
  }, 5000)
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="spinner" style="display:none">This is a spinner</div>
<button id="button">Click</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this is more along the lines of what you would like:

```js
setTimeout(() => {
  document.getElementsByClassName('spinning-icon-two')[0].style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementsByClassName('hidden-page')[0].style.display = 'block';
}, 5000);
```

```css
.spinning-icon {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="hidden-page" style="display:none;">
  This was the hidden page while the div was shown the loading icon.
</div>

<div class="spinning-icon-two" style="width:100%;height:0;padding-bottom:100%;position:relative;"><iframe src="https://giphy.com/embed/t8WHEAfuku6muxkGPo" width="100%" height="100%" style="position:absolute" frameBorder="0" class="giphy-embed" allowFullScreen></iframe></div>
<p><a href="https://giphy.com/gifs/perfect-loops-t8WHEAfuku6muxkGPo">via GIPHY</a></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick. You can modify it accordingly to fit your need.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#edit-submit').click(function(){
    $("#spinner").css('display', 'block');
    setTimeout(function (){
      location.href = 'https://jsfiddle.net/TebogoJSF/sp5kzq2m/5/';
    }, 5000);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="spinner" style="display:none">
  <img src="https://media.giphy.com/media/3o7bu3XilJ5BOiSGic/giphy.gif" width="25">
</div>
<button id="edit-submit">
Click Me
</button>
```